# Why use Faraday over Net::HTTP?

Tags: ruby, wrapper, faraday

Why would someone use the Faraday gem vs directly using Net::HTTP?   What is the benefit of using a wrapper like this?

Comment: This is going to draw opinions, not facts.

Comment: There are objective reasons to use Faraday over Net::HTTP.

Answer (score 14):

Using the `Net::HTTP` adapter directly is fine, it's just binding your code to a particular interface which may differ from alternate tools. The main reason one would use [`Faraday`](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) is that it wraps multiple adapters, one of which is `Net::HTTP`. If you're using `Faraday` and start out with `Net:HTTP`, you can later decide to use [`Excon`](https://github.com/geemus/excon), [`Typhoeus`](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus), [`Patron`](http://toland.github.io/patron/) or [`EventMachine`](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request) without changing more than a line or two of configuration. Had you used `Net::HTTP` directly, you'd have to change a lot of implementation-specific code to switch to another adapter.

Comment: Good explanation. You should also mention middleware. For example, I use JSON middleware to automatically encode my request as JSON and decode the response from JSON.

Comment: Faraday should also help normalize exceptions across all of the libraries as well, correct?

Comment: Yes @user3084728, Faraday will catch each adapter's exceptions and re-throw them as Faraday exceptions.